# How to modify Webpack config js file to include Webtorrent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webtorrent

I'm building a React project and want to include Webtorrent in it. I npm installed Webtorrent and am using Webpack to bundle. In the webtorrent docs it says that I have to include this:

```
{
 target: 'web',
 node: {
  fs: 'empty'
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [
  // make sure to install the 'json-loader' package: npm install json-loader
   {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json'
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

In my `webpack.config.js` file, in order to include the json-loader package(and also npm install json-loader, which I have).

My Webpack.config.js file now looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/carolAG/rva51akn/

but I still get an error on my terminal and can't use webpack.

This is the error:

> ERROR in ./~/webtorrent/package.json
>   Module parse failed: /Users/carolgonzalez/Documents/Locker/node_modules/webtorrent/package.json Unexpected token (2:8)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:8)
>
> ERROR in ./~/webtorrent/lib/torrent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/carolgonzalez/Documents/Locker/node_modules/webtorrent/lib
>    @ ./~/webtorrent/lib/torrent.js 13:9-22

The error is longer but this is what I think is the relevant parts of it.

I want to to know:

- Am I including the Webpack.config.js loader correctly?
- What does the `fs`, key under the `node` obj doing with the val `empty`?
- Is the reason I can't use Webtorrent to do with the loader or am I missing something else?